# dereferencing c-pointer in LabVIEW

Tags: pointers, dereference, labview

My .DLL function outputs a C-pointer to a string which I need to dereference. I realized that I need to dereference the pointer twice, and I know there should be a built in function in LabVIEW which does just that. But I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Isn't it possible to call the DLL with a string, and in the calling configuration insert a **string?

Comment: If you're calling your DLL function from LabVIEW, you can instruct LabVIEW to allocate the necessary memory for you. Then your function simply has to copy the data in. This however gets a bit more complicated if you don't know the maximum length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, any memory that will exist in LabVIEW needs to be allocated in LabVIEW.  So allocate a `char` buffer in LabVIEW and pass it in as a `String` and `CStr Pointer` in the Call Library Function.

Do everything you can in C and toss the results back out into Labview in a `CStr`.

**WARNING: If you `memcpy()` outside the bounds of the allocated memory, Labview will most likely crash and you won't be able to catch the error.  So either use try / catch with secure version of `memcpy`, over allocate in Labview, or test sizes.**

```
C++:
void TestDLL(char Name[], int SizeOfLabviewMemory){
    char *StringInC = "Hello World!"; 
    int SmallerStringSize = 0;
    if(strlen(StringInC) < SizeOfLabviewMemory){
         SmallerStringSize = strlen(StringInC); 
    }else{
         SmallerStringSize = SizeOfLabviewMemory;
    }

    memcpy(Name, StringInC, SizeOfLabviewMemory);  
}
```